# Rails - how to store collections for forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I best work with collections for input in forms? I re-use them in several forms. i.e. where to store and how to use in a DRY way?

Examples

- collection: ["NL","EN"] - this is cross-model
- collection: Annotation.order(:name).where(:sender => @document.sender_id, :documenttype => @document.documenttype_id) - dynamic / on other attributes of the instance

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to share data among your views? The simplest solution would be to define helper methods in `ApplicationHelper`.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def languages
    [:NL, :EN]
  end

  def document_annotations(sender_id, document_type_id)
    Annotation.order(:name).where(:sender => sender_id, :documenttype => document_type_id)
  end
end
```

On the other note, it seems like your array might logically belong to one of your classes in your domain. If there is a class that can it belongs to then use constants:

```
class SomeModelProbably
    LANGS = [:NL, :EN]
end

# Then access it like this:
SomeModelProbably::LANGS
```

Also, that `Annotation` filtering would probably be better rewritten as a scope:

```
class Annotation
  scope :by_sender_and_doc_type, ->(doc) { order(:name).where(:sender => doc.sender_id, :documenttype => doc.document_type_id) }
end

# Then access it like this:
Annotation.by_sender_and_doc_type(@document)
```

Comment: How would i access the languages if stored in the `ApplicationHelper`

Comment: Simply call that helper method in your view.

Comment: how does that work? I use simple form `<%= f.input :locale_language, label: 'Doc. language', languages , prompt:'Select language' %>` does not work